# how to navigate to previously viewed page in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jquerymobile template being implemented which will further be used for phonegap deployment for devices - iphone and android phones. I have 11 Div's with data-role as "page". Each Page header has a Back button which should actually go back to its parent screen. At this moment, I am doing it with an anchor

`<a href="#loginpage" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-inline="true">Back</a>`

So when I click on back in my above example, it takes me to Loginpage. But is there something else that can be tried instead of anchor tag, which is actually failing in the following scenario?

**flow a.** Screen 1 -> Screen 3

**flow b.** Screen 2 -> Screen 3

In **flow "a"** -> When I click "Back" in Screen 3 it should go back to Screen 1

In **flow "b"** -> When I click "Back" in Screen 3 it should go back to Screen 2

My flow fails here on Screen 3 using an anchor, because am not able to get the navigation back to which screen I actually navigated from.

Waiting for some help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple.

See jQuery mobile documentation here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

"Back" button links section.

```
<a data-rel="back">Go Back</a>
```

Also, the button can be generated automatically in each page header by adding the following to the page div:

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

You can also make every page to show back button by default by adding the following to the  code which is run after jQuery mobile is initialized:

```
  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
```

This as well as a few more options, such as the default back button text can be found here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Section Adding Back buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try setting data-rel="back" 
Refer the documentation
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
$('.anchors_you_need_to_capture').click(function(e){
history.pushState(e.target.href);
}
```

It adds a the clicked page to the history so when you click back it will go to the last clicked linked.